# dev/sda2 almost full; Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox

I work in Ubuntu 22 on VirtualBox. /dev/sda3 is almost full:

```
df -h --total
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           720M  1,6M  718M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        24G   23G  411M  99% /
tmpfs           3,6G     0  3,6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2       512M  6,1M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           720M  124K  720M   1% /run/user/1000
total            30G   23G  5,9G  80% -
```

I have cleared unused linux kernels following [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) which freed only 1%. What else can I do?

I added additional GBs to my virtual hard disk and with GParted added ample GBs to /dev/sda2.

`df -h --total` now reads

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           720M  1,6M  718M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        25G   23G  115M 100% /
tmpfs           3,6G     0  3,6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2        11G  6,1M   11G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           720M  116K  720M   1% /run/user/1000
total            40G   23G   16G  60% -
```

Nevertheless I still get an error message "Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root".

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Kernels should be on the boot partition, /dev/sda2, in your case. Uninstall stuff or delete large files to free space.

Comment: @mikewhatever it is a fresh Ubuntu installation, not much installed. Should I increase the size of the virtual disk?

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, `/dev/sda2` looks fine with only 1% in use. But `/dev/sda3` is almost full.

Comment: @mpboden, I will repartition the virtual hard disk. What is the optimum size of `/dev/sda2`?

Comment: Again, I don’t see a problem with `sda2`. Why do you think you need to resize it?

Comment: @mpboden isn't there too much memory allocated to /dev/sda2. I will transfer memory from sda2 to sda3.

Comment: Are you confusing the difference between `/boot` on `sda2` and the root directory `/` on `sda3`? 1Gb is more than sufficient for the `/boot` directory on `sda2`. You initially had 500mb and that was fine as well. Your root directory on `sda3` is full. So you need to look there and find out what is taking up so much space or allocate more to `sda3`.

Comment: @mpboden I moved memory from `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/sda3`. Now the error message no longer appears.